Is Hausdorff convergence well behaved with regard to complements of sets?
Let $(X,d)$ be a compact (metric) space and $(A_n)$ a sequence of closed sets in $X$. Let $H$-$\lim_nA_n=A$ (the Hausdorff limit of $(A_n)$). Does $H$-$\lim_n(X\setminus A_n)$ exists? If yes, how is it related to $X\setminus A$? Here $X\setminus S$ is the complement of a set $S$ in $X$ with respect to $X$.

I think it is better to write $H$-$\lim_n A_n$ and not $H-\lim_n A_n$.  The second one looks like a subtraction.

One example to ponder, in $X=[0,1]$: enumerate the dyadic rationals in $(0,1)$ in the order $(a_k) = (\frac12,\frac14,\frac34,\frac18,\frac38,\frac58,\frac78,\frac1{16},\ldots)$; and take $A_n = {a_1,\dots,a_n}$. Then I believe that both the Hausdorff limit of $(A_n)$ is $X$ and the Hausdorff limit of $(X\setminus A_n)$ is $X$.

The claim “Moreover $\delta>0$ can be small enough so that $B(x,\delta)\cap A_\varepsilon = \varnothing$” is wrong. Your $\varepsilon$ has already been fixed at the start, so it could easily be the case that $x \in A_\varepsilon$ to start with. The same issue happens with your choice of $\delta_n > 0$ later.

Also (to OP), “by Blaschke’s theorem $A$ must also be compact” doesn’t make sense. You can certainly choose a compact limit $A$. But if you’re including non-closed sets to start with, the limit is not unique, so $A$ might as well be not closed. For example $d(X, A) = 0$ for any dense $A$, so the constant sequence $A_n = X$ convergences to any dense $A$.

Also, another issue is that $A$ may equal $X$, so it may not make sense to talk about converging in Hausdorff distance to $X \setminus A$, since Hausdorff distance is only defined for nonempty subsets.

@GregMartin That is true, but the question is a bit problematic in the first place since $X \setminus A_n$ could be non-closed in the first place and the Hausdorff “metric” is only a pseudometric applying to possibly non-closed subsets, so the limit may not be unique. If $A$ is, say, the set of all dyadic rationals in $[0, 1]$, say, then you actually do have $A_n \to A$ and $X \setminus A_n \to X \setminus A$, despite both sequences also converging to $X$. (And in case $A = X$, the Hausdorff distance from $X \setminus A_n$ to $X \setminus A = \varnothing$ is not defined in the first place.)

I’ve already mentioned several issues with both the question and the proposed proof in the comments. Here is a counterexample showing that the result is false with the unique compact limit $A$ being not the entirety of $X$ (as in Greg Martin’s comment): Let $X = \{-1\} \cup [0, 1]$, $A_n = [\frac{1}{n}, 1]$. Then $A = [0, 1]$, and,
$$d(X \setminus A_n, X \setminus A) = d(\{-1\} \cup [0, \frac{1}{n}), \{-1\}) = 1 + \frac{1}{n} \not\to 0$$
